# Theorem Inside Tabular Environment

Tags: tables, theorems

I'm putting together a Beamer presentation and want a theorem to appear on the left side of the slide and a picture on the right side. I tried to accomplish this with:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{lc}
\begin{theorem}theorem here\end{theorem}&picture here
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
```

The result is a bunch of "missing endgroup" errors. Can I accomplish what I want with tabular or some other environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could place the theorem and the picture in separate, side-by=side `minipage` environments:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx} % just for this example
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A theorem and a picture, side-by-side}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{theorem}theorem here\end{theorem}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{\fill} % spacing between the minipages
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{demo.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I use overprint within the minipages, the resulting output has the minipages stacked vertically for some reason. Wrapping the entire business in a tabular (a minipage in each cell) seems to keep the minipages side by side.

Comment: @AustinMohr - Please see the augmented answer for a demo of how the two minipages can co-exist side-by-side. How are you setting up the picture?

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to stick with a `tabular`, you can do so by using a `paragraphy` style column:

```
  \begin{tabular}{p{.5\textwidth}c}
```

Here's a complete MWE.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{p{.5\textwidth}c}
    \begin{theorem}theorem here
    \end{theorem} & picture here
    \end{tabular}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to add `@{}` to the left of the first column and to the right of the second column to eliminate the unneeded (and probably undesirable) intercolumn whitespaces.